# Jar won't play sounds from resources folder loaded through getClass()

Tags: java, audio, jar, executable-jar, javasound

I have this directory structure:

```
root
  resources
    .png files
    Music.mid
    Sound.wav
  src
    .java files
```

and I play the sounds from the resources folder using this code

```
    public void play()  {
        try  {
            URL defaultSound = getClass().getResource(filename);
            AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
                    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(defaultSound);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start( );
            while (clip.isRunning()) {}

        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I pass to it filenames = `/resources/Music.mid` and `/resources/Sound.wav`.

It works fine when I run it in IDE, but when I package it into jar (all music files are inside the jar, I checked) it doesn't play sound and throws exception:

```
FileNotFoundException: syntax error in file name, directory name or disk name.
```

Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Can you provide the entire stack trace and a [mre]?

Comment: Before I offer my answer, could you try the following test? For grins, (as a temporary thing while figuring this out) make a copy of the directory "resources" and its contents, and add it as subfolder of "src". I'm curious if the "/" symbol as the start of the filename is directing getResource() to use the "root" as you have posted your structure as the root folder, or if it thinks "src" is the root folder for this "absolute address" invocation. Other than that what you posted looks like it should work. The stack trace wouldn't hurt. Is the error on the URL or AudioInputStream line?

Answer (score 0):

getClass() returns a URL and not a File object. It does that because classloaders (which is what .getResource uses) are an abstract concept, and 'a resource' can be anything. It does not have to be a file. It can be an entry in a jar file (which is really a zip). It can be an entry in a jmod file (which is a custom container format introduced with JDK9). It can be a blob in a database column. A file on a webdav server. Or even generated on the fly every time you ask for the resource. Anything goes.

Clearly, your audio player library is obsolete or crappy. It *DOES* allow you to pass a URL to it, but the audio player library you're using will just crash out if that URL is anything except one that represents an actual file on disk.

When running in the IDE, it *IS* a file on disk. When running as a jar, it is as valid a resource as anything a classloader produces, but due to the failure of this player library to deal with any URL (other than file:// URLs), it crashes.

There are only two solutions:

1. Get a better library.
2. Find a temp dir, unpack the resource into it, then hand the temp file (or possibly a URL representing this temp file) to your library.

Option #2 is quite hairy. You need to find a location with write access, and you need to take care of deleting the file after. It's also a waste of disk cycles. But if you must, you can, of course, do so:

```
public void play() throws Exception {
  File f = File.createTempFile("Sound.wav");
  f.deleteOnExit();
  try (InputStream in = YourPlayer.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/Sound.wav");
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
     in.transferTo(out);
  }

  AudioInputStream audioInputStream = 
                    AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f.toURI().toURL());
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioInputStream);
            clip.start( );
            while (clip.isRunning()) {}
}
```

NB: `getClass().getResource()` is slightly wrong; the right syntax is `ClassThisCodeIsIn.class.getResource`. Usually both work, but there are cases where the latter works but the former doesn't (such as when you're subclassing). It's a good habit to never write code that is strictly inferior to something that's just as simple, even if in this particular case it probably doesn't matter.